# Using double vendor prefixes for animations and other attributes

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, vendor-prefix

I'm diddling with some css animations and I came to a small dilemma when it came to adding the vendor prefixes. I know that the "keyframes" property requires explicit defining with vendor prefixes just as much as some other CSS properties like "transform". However, what I've been wondering is whether I should include the vendor prefixes on both parts or the "keyframes" would be sufficient.
Here is an example of what I mean:

ex1:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation_name {
    0% {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateZ(180deg);}
}
```

ex2:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation_name {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);}
}
```

Which would be more correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 2, as this is the style of output I would expect from an autoprefixer tool, for example: [enter link description here](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dom_ahdigital.